# Does the FileInfo.GetFiles method in .NET CF retrieve all files recursively?

Tags: .net, compact-framework, filesystems

I see .NET has the option: `SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly` which helps me to limit the file list retrieval for just the selected directory, not subdirectories. I would like to know whether .NET CF has any options to do so?

Comment: I just want to get just files in the selected directories, not all files in subdirectories. Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

The .Net Compact Framework has no built-in methods that recurse subdirectories.

If you just want to get the files that are directly in a directory (and not the subdirectories), you can simply call `Directory.GetFiles`.

Comment: Sorry, it's DirectoryInfo, new DirectoryInfo(...).GetFiles(path)

Comment: I think you have not gotten my idea, I just want to get just files in the selected directories, not all files in subdirectories. Is there any way?

Comment: `TopDirectoryOnly` is the default.  You can just call `GetFiles`.